# Setting up font of TextBox from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

How do I set the font of a `TextBox` from a `string` in the code behind?

```
// example
txtEditor.FontFamily = "Consolas";
```

Comment: Not a stupid question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
txtEditor.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas"); // the Media namespace
```

Comment: If `txtEditor` is a [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is no FontFamily property on that object, but there is a [Font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 20):

Use the following syntax:

```
lblCounting.Font  = new Font("Times New Roman", 50);
```

Where `lblCounting` is just any label.

Comment: Use the markdown and formatting tools to make your code display as code: `lblCounting.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 50);`

Answer (score 8):

```
System.Drawing.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: The question asked how to set the Font but the example implied the OP wanted to set the FontFamily.  This answer answers the question if not the example and is the answer I was searching for (though I needed to correct it a bit.)

Comment: To be sure, the OP said nothing about FontFamily in the question, but you are right that it is in the example, but only for the TextBox, rather than setting the Font program-wide.

Answer (score 3):

Copy and paste your example code into the constructor of the form, right after `InitializeComponent();`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtEditor.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to do it globally, programmatically:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use txtEditor.Font.Name = "Consolas";